# Debug 2 Applications on 1 android device

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I am reposting this important question - 
I have one app that should call another app, each one is located in a different workspace.

I want to debug both of them (on the same device)

How can I do it if at all?

(older question: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437580/debug-multiple-android-applications-simultaneously-on-one-device))

Comment: Good question. Your first application runs second one , As I understood it must debug the second one, I think you must look for how to debug second application from first one for getting what you want

Comment: I believe, but can't test it now, that IDEA has a feature to attach the debugger to a running process (i.e. the 2nd app) and doing so will open a second DDMS perspetive.  I'm sure Eclipse has the same thing - or am I missing the point?

Answer (score 0):

As you are having one device, you can use one AVD instance of Eclipse IDE with that device. You can send call from AVD instance to your physical device and so you can debug or test your app well.

Comment: I'm not sure how it should work , the AVD is a different device, both my apps runs on the same device. the "intent" will not be exists on the AVD and the call will fail...